# Wordpress - Using a database to update custom posts

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that utilizes a custom post type, call it CPT-1, that I created using JetEngine. Inside of CPT-1 are meta fields. Once that was setup, I did a bulk insert of data using Ultimate CSV Importer Pro and it put this information into CPT-1 and I could put each column of data into the meta fields I wanted to use. These fields are then used later in tables.

Is there a way to go around the CSV Importer part of this process and just pull from a database? In the long term, i'd like to make changes to certain posts and upload different posts while using CPT-1 but I don't think using a CSV every time will be easy or accurate. If I could just pull from a database that I make updates to, I can track those changes easily and manage it.

I have database experience but not so much with Wordpress databases. What tables would I have to pay attention to if I were to go down this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress uses MySQL as a backend, so there is no reason you can't just insert the data directly. You'll need to get the credentials Wordpress uses to connect to the database, and then connect yourself, probably from your own custom PHP script.

I am generally skiddish doing things like you described because Wordpress is a complex piece of software and I don't have a lot of awareness of what it is doing behind-the-scenes (nor do they really *intend* users to have such awareness, most functionality is hidden from the user.)

However, if you have been doing a CSV import, and you have tested it extensively, and it's working fine with that method, there is no reason you couldn't carry out this same thing with less manual work on your part via a PHP script.

I'm afraid I can't get much more specific in my answer because I don't have information about what exactly you did with the CSV.

A straightforward (but not super efficient) way of doing this would be a PHP script where you initiate a database connection to the database you update, and a second connection to the MySQL database, fetch a query of whatever rows you want to update (whatever you would normally be exporting via CSV) and iterate row-by-row and insert this data into the MySQL database. You can make this significantly more efficient by making a single prepared statement, and then executing it repeatedly with each row of values.

A more efficient way of doing it would be to pull the data into your PHP script and then format it as a single query which you could then add into the MySQL database.

If you already have CSV importing working, you could even do a "lazy" solution where you just write a PHP script that generates a CSV and then feeds it into MySQL and imports it the same way your other program was. It's hard for me to tell from what you said, which of these solutions would work. However, I have used all three solutions, depending on what I'm doing and what kind of error handling I want.

In general, if errors happen rarely-to-never you are probably better off with the single, bulk insert methods whether one query or PHP automating the export of a CSV and then passing it to be imported into Wordpress' MySQL database.

Comment: Thank you @cazort for the explaination and possible routes that I could take. I'm going to keep going through the CSV import phase and seeing how the tables change with meta values and posts. Essentially the custom post types all me to filter down the posts I want to focus on and if need be I can try to change associations with the meta table that is created when I use JetEngine.